# Conflicting triggers in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I have two tables as follows:

- `department(alpha, college, etc.)`
- `course(id, alpha, college, title, etc.)`

College and alpha are present in both tables by design. I decided to de-normalize a little because the college and alpha are always desired when viewing a course.

I have one trigger that executes after the `department` table is updated so that it updates all rows in the `course` table with the new `alpha` and `college` values. I also have a trigger that executes before updating the `course` table to make sure that the `alpha`-`college` pair that the user submitted in his or her edits exists in the `department` table; if the pair isn't there it raises and application error.

These triggers conflict. The second one checks that the new values for the `department` table are in their, but they aren't yet so it fails like it should.

Is it possible to ignore the second trigger if the first trigger is executed first? I really don't want to execute the second trigger in this case, since I know the values are in the first table. If that's not possible, is there a better way to do this without changing my schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second trigger sounds like nothing more than a foreign key.  Drop it and create a foreign key constraint on `course` instead.  That works in my tests.

However, it seems like unnecessary work to support a denormalization that provides little benefit.  If you just want to write simple queries, create a view that joins the two tables and use that in your queries.  If you are concerned about the join performance, I doubt very much that it will be a problem, unless you are missing obvious indexes on the tables.

Comment: I think I might go with this. I'm usually not the DBA, but he got hit by a bus.

Answer (score 2):

I would sincerely recommend removing your trigger approach all together since it's burdened by dirty reads. Whenever I faced a challenge such as this I would implement the DML using Stored Procedures only. You get all the advantages of triggers without the headaches if implemented properly.

If your fear is you want to make sure all updates to the department table follow your logic as do changes in course, remove update permissions to any user except the owner of the stored procedure. This ensures the only caller who can modify that table is the stored procedure you control and understand. And by coincidence, it becomes the only way to update the tables.

Just $0.02

Comment: I was thinking of doing this if there was no other way. I just don't feel like making any more stored procedures. :-P

Comment: This is good advice, but writing stored procedures is not a substitute for declaring proper integrity constraints -- in this case a foreign key from course to department.  The constraint will help ensure that your code is correct.

Comment: Excellent Point Dave =) +1 to you

Answer (score 2):

Like most other cases implemented with triggers, you can see the burden here because the data-model itself has defects.

You can implement the same logic as below and maintain all rules using PK and FK constraints.

```
---Department references College...

Create table department(
   department_id number primary key,
   aplha varchar2(20) not null,
   college varchar2(20) not null
);

***--Course belongs to a department.. so should be a child of department.
--If it's possible for different depts to give the same course (IT and CS), 
--you'll have 
--a dept_course_asc table***

Create table Course(
    course_id number primary key
    department_id number references department(department_id),
    course_name varchar2(100) not null
);
```

if you have a student table, you'll associate it with the course table with another student_table association table.

It might appear these are a lot more tables than you intially showed, but if you want to avoid data redundancies and don't want to have the burden of updating columns in all tables whenever they change in the parent table, the above model is the only way to go.

Comment: the alpha is the department. you have added data to this problem. your college table is completely useless.

Comment: the only benefit you have added (once i take away your added data) is the fk in course. but, like i said in the question, i de-normalized by copying that one field from department to course to avoid the join for one single field. if you are arguing that i should perform that join every time, then say that.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree I added data based on other questions I have seen before and I couldn't really understand "alpha" means "department". Modified the post now. And yes, I believe you should join the two tables based on the psuedo-key department id instead of alpha and college.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to the problem.

**Solution 1: Using DEFERRABLE FK constraint.**

This solution is only possible if (alpha, college) combination is unique and can be defined as a PK for department table.
In this case, you do not need the trigger on the course table.

Instead, you define a DEFERRABLE FK (alpha, college) on course that referenced the department table.

And before the update on department you must execute SET CONSTRAINT ... DEFERRED statement [see documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10003.htm#i2066960).
Then the FK will be not verified until the commit.

**Solution 2: Using system context**

You switch off the second trigger using the local system_context.

The context must be created first. [see User Created Contexts](http://psoug.org/reference/sys_context.html)

The trigger on department set a variable in the context to a some value.

And in the second trigger on courses you check the value of the variable in the context